# Mixamo/Animation Merge animations

Tags: animation, rigging

I would like to ask a question about "Mixamo". Is there any way you could mix multiple animations and start them from different location. For example my animation (1.running) goes from point A to B and I want to start animation(2.running jump) from point B. But when I move those animations they change, so basicaly animation (1.running) starts at point B if I move it slightly.

Also I tried to use different plugins for combining them as GODOT GAME TOOLS. But this doesn't work so well...

If you guys understand me please help me.[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use Print Screen to take a screen shot, for Win 10 you can also use Shift + Windows Key + S to capture a portion of the screen.

Comment: The technique is called "Animation Blending" and in Blender is usually done with NLA tracks.  I recommend reading up on that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put all mixamo animations to a single armature using nla tracks.
I made a script for automating it.

You can try a script that i wrote. It combines all .fbx anim files that you downloaded from mixamo into one armature.

[gumroad.com/l/MixAnimMerger](http://gumroad.com/l/MixAnimMerger)

You can then skin the mesh to the new armature and export it as fbx.it will contain all animations.